# ubuntu studio failing to install opera

Tags: 12.04, opera

I have an old laptop and the only OS that will work on it was Ubuntu 10.
Then I tried Ubuntu Studio and that works so far so good.

For consistency I use Opera on all of my other computers, an AppleMac, a PC as well as two PC laptops. Opera will simply not load onto Linux Studio, very sad, as the laptop is still very good, an old *Fujitsu Lifebook 8200E* with 2GB Ram.

Is there anybody anywhere that can help me save the Fujitsu from the scrapheap, I would be very grateful for any help/advise.

Comment: what do you mean, it won't load? have you tried to install it? if you mean that it won't start, what happens when you run it from the command line? what error do you get?

Comment: of course Ubuntu Studio 16.04 is loaded, it is just impossible to get Opera loaded my next move is to wipe it clean again and to try to make it happen with Ubuntu 12.04, if that won't work I shall abandon Linux and look for another laptop, a monumental shame!!!

Comment: for all the community, I have managed to put Opera on finally, how? first I deleted Ubuntu Studio then I replaced it with Ubuntu 10.4 then again with 14.04 then I updated to Ubuntu 16.04 which allowed me to download Opera and installed it, Hooray, I do not have to throw this old Fujitsu Lifebook 8200E in the bin , great result eventually, took me five days!!!
Thank you all I hope this helps others
@Graham